# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_io.TextIOWrapper") to str

Tags: python

Olá, Eu estou a tentar fazer um Assisstente Virtual, mas está me a dar um erro que eu não percebo o que esta acontecendo

```
name = open("user_data.txt")
user = name.read()

def main():
    main_question = input("O que deseja, " + name + "?")
```

E dá o seguinte erro:

```
    main_question = input("O que deseja, " + name + "?")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_io.TextIOWrapper") to str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro está ocorrendo pois você está passando a variável `name` que abre o arquivo para leitura. Você deveria usar a variável `user` pois você já fez a chamada do método `.read()` nela que retorna o conteúdo do arquivo.

```py
   main_question = input("O que deseja, " + user + "?")
```